# Access BIGNUM bits in OpenSSL 1.1?

Tags: api, openssl, bignum

Prior 1.1 version of OpenSSL API I had access to raw representation of BIGNUM types through "d" field in struct bignum_st:

```
   struct bignum_st
           {
           BN_ULONG *d;    /* Pointer to an array of 'BN_BITS2' bit chunks. */
           int top;        /* Index of last used d +1. */
           /* The next are internal book keeping for bn_expand. */
           int dmax;       /* Size of the d array. */
           int neg;        /* one if the number is negative */
           int flags;
           };
```

In my program I need to get lowest byte from BIGNUM after some computations - it is quite easily - simply as:

```
(bn->d[0] & 0xff)
```

With API of OpenSSL version 1.1 many BN internals have been made opaque - I cannot get direct access to representation of BIGNUM. I still can get raw representation, but with additional copying - either `BN_bn2bin` or `BN_mask_bits`.

There is any way to access lowest byte without extra copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is any way to access lowest byte without extra copying?

Yes and no. If the `BIGNUM` is smaller that `0xffffffff`, then use [`BN_get_word(bn) & 0xff;`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_get_word.html).

If your `BIGNUM` is larger than `0xffffffff`, then use [`BN_bn2binpad`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bn2binpad.html) to copy out a range of bytes.

Also see [Issue 2001, Please provide BIGNUM And, Or and Xor ops](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2001) in the OpenSSL bug tracker.